# Accessing ActiveRecord Models after a `db:test:prepare` in a Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

In my Rails app, I have created a rake task that resets the database with `db:reset`, prepares the testing database with `db:test:prepare` and then attempts to repopulate the database with example data using ActiveRecord:

```
namespace :db do
  task :repopulate => :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke
    puts Course.first.inspect
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the task fails when I run it, complaining that it `Could not find table 'courses'`. Furthermore, it doesn't seem to have prepared the test database correctly, because my tests all fail until I manually run `rake db:test:prepare`. If I comment out the line that invokes `db:test:prepare` everything seems to work fine (except, of course, that it doesn't prepare the test database). Any ideas what the problem is or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try Course.reset_column_information after the rake tasks.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that for all tables in my database?